# Javascript: Create new arrays from a url of object of arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, lodash, javascript-objects

I currently have a url of objects of arrays being served from here https://s3.amazonaws.com/blockseed.website/performance.json , I want to extract the data from there using vanilla JS, JQuery or Lodash and create new array like this
[image]

This the object of arrays that is currently being served from the url as a json
[image]

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: ... and at least `enter image description here` or even better add code as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can simply get the data by key:**

`data.performance.fundBtcArr` ,`data.performance.fundUsdArr`,`data.performance.btcUsdArr`

```js
var data={"performance": {"datesArr": ["2018-04-30", "2018-05-07", "2018-05-14", 
    "2018-05-21", "2018-05-28", "2018-06-04", "2018-06-11", "2018-06-18", "2018-06-25", "2018-07-02", "2018-07-09"], 
    "fundBtcArr": [1, 0.956157566, 0.988963214, 0.992333066, 1.118842298, 1.064376568, 1.109733638, 1.082080679, 1.142624866, 
        1.1107828743809005, 1.0626307952408292], 
        "fundUsdArr": [1, 0.974710531, 0.944055086, 0.903073518, 0.869041365, 0.870284702, 0.815468401, 0.789070479, 
            0.777083258, 0.8027552300742684, 0.7766297878480255], 
            "btcUsdArr": [1, 1.019403669, 0.954590699, 0.910050818, 0.77673267, 0.81764737, 0.734832552, 0.729215939, 0.680086073, 
                0.7226932000744855, 0.7308557133166972]

                }}
                
     //console.log(data.performance.datesArr);              
   var  fundBtcArr=data.performance.fundBtcArr ;
   fundBtcArr.unshift('fund/Btc %');
 
  console.log(fundBtcArr); 
  var  fundUsdArr=data.performance.fundUsdArr ;
  fundUsdArr.unshift('fund/Usd %');
   console.log(fundUsdArr); 
   var  btcUsdArr=data.performance.btcUsdArr ;
  btcUsdArr.unshift('btc/Usd %');
   console.log(btcUsdArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

const {performance} = `Your Json Variable`;

const {btcUsdArr,datesArr,fundBtcArr,fundUsdArr} = performance;

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems destructuring isn't supported by IE (correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Yes looks like IE dosen't support it